# Differential Equations Mixture Tank Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A 49-gallon tank initially holds 9 gallons of a salt water solution, of concentration 1/3 lbs of salt per gallon. A new solution, of concentration 1/2 lbs of salt per gallon, is poured in at a rate of 4 gallons a minute. If the mixture is only drained at 2 gallons per minute, find the concentration in the tank just before it overflows.

I can find the rate in, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what the rate out is. I think I'm making a small error in my work that is throwing me off, thanks in advance for the help! It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$S(t)=$ mass of salt in the tank in the tank, in lbs.
$C_i=$ Concentration of salt being poured Into the tank.  Note: these two are *not* merely initial rates.
$r_i=$ Rate of fluid being pumped Into the tank, in gallons per minute.
$C_l=$ Concentration of salt in the tank or leaving the tank.
$r_l=$ Rate of fluid leaving the tank, in gallons per minute.

Note: There are at least two different kinds of rates in many of these types of questions.  Volume or fluid flow is typically $\frac{volume}{time}$ or in this exercise, $\frac{gallons}{minute}$.
We also need $\frac{mass\space of\space salt}{minute}$.
This comes from mass of salt flow $=r \cdot C$
Of course each of these two rates also has an inflow version and a leaving version.

The rate out is a combination of volume out with concentration in the tank.
The volume out is given as a constant rate $2 \space\frac{gals}{min.}$
However, the mass of salt leaving a tank is
$$ 2\cdot\frac{C_l}{V(t)} $$
However, the volume of solution in the tank varies according to $$V(t) = 9 + (4-2)t = 9 + 2t$$

This makes mass of salt leaving the tank
$$ 2\cdot\frac{C_l}{9+2t} $$

The differential equation then is
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=4\cdot\frac12-2\cdot\frac{C_l}{9+2t}$$

[Excellent resource with a similar question fully explained.](https://www.kristakingmath.com/blog/mixing-problems-differential-equations)

Answer (score 0):

> If the mixture is only drained at 2 gallons per minute. . .

Is this not the rate out?

Comment: In one sense, yes, that is the rate out, but if we're tracking the rate at which the quantity of salt is leaving the system, then it's no longer so simple as it's a function Q(t) and I just can't seem to figure it out.